# Plot a figure on a canvas

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, qt-designer

I am using Qt Designer and matplotlib for plotting.

So far, I've promoted a Qwidget to a Canvas class and draw my plots on it by creating axes and plotting them with figure.add_subplot(), so code looks this way:

```
ax = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(data)

self.canvas.draw()
```

But now I have a figure object and I need to plot it. Is there a way to do that without instanciating axes and assigning them to a figure? Is there a way I can do :
"self.canvas.add_figure" ? Because in my case I don't have access to the axes.

Edit : here's the code of the canvas.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt4 import QtGui
class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
```

Comment: I think the canvas you use is a figure, you could show more code to understand you better, also because you say you can not access the axes. Make them class members with self.ax = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111) then obj.ax.plot()

Comment: You cannot *add* a figure to a canvas. The canvas is associated with exactly one figure, which is passed to the constructor. I don't think it can be changed later (assigning to `self.figure` seems to fail in horrible ways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be due to wrong assumtions: If you have a figure and that figure contains one or more axes, you can access the axes via `fig.get_axes()`. If the figure does not contain axes, you can still add axes to it via `fig.add_subplot()` or `fig.add_axes()`. 
So the problem you are trying to solve here, might be easily circumvented.

Coming to the question itself. A canvas is always associated with a figure. A canvas without figure makes no sense. There are two options:

#### 1. Create the canvas with the available figure

You may delay the creation of the `FigureCanvas` until you have access to the figure you want to show.

```
self.figure = <figure you want to show>
FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
```

#### 2. Replace the canvas

You may replace the canvas you already have with a canvas that hosts the new figure to show.

```
self.layout().removeWidget(self.canvas)
# create a new canvas
self.figure = <figure you want to show>
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
# add the new canvas at the position of the old one
self.layout().addWidget(self.canvas, 1)
self.canvas.draw()
self.parent.parent.processEvents()
```